# Multiple MTLDevice instances in Metal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics, metal

Can we have more than one device declared in a Metal app? I declared two devices, device and a defaultDevice.
When I use defaultDevice instead of device, I get an exception on the lines of "found nil while unwrapping..".
Also, is there a naing convention for declaring a device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, it is just possible to have one device per GPU. Since you mostly have one GPU you can create just one device (see the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html)). The second device will therefore be empty (nil)

But I think it is possible to have multiple command queues on a single device. It should therefore not be necessary to create multiple devices.

Answer (score -1):

Good quote from [metalbyexample.com](http://metalbyexample.com/up-and-running-1/)

> A device is an abstraction around the GPU. It provides methods for creating objects like command queues, render states, and libraries. We’ll look at each of these in turn shortly.

Also a quote from apple documentation about [MTLDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MTLDevice):

> The MTLDevice protocol defines the interface to a single graphics
>   processor (GPU). You use an object that conforms to this protocol to
>   query the capabilities of the processor and to allocate objects used
>   to access those capabilities.

So I think it will not be possible to have multiple devices (even on macs with can have descrete and internal graphic devices) because only one device generates image on your screen.

Comment: This isn't true. You could have multiple devices on machines with multiple GPUs like the Mac Pro or Retina Macbook Pro because even devices not drawing can be used for compute. Tower Mac Pros can also have more than one actively drawing GPU. Metal is not just for drawing though.

On iOS it's currently a good assumption, but not necessarily a safe assumption.

Using the default device is best practice, but do remember on Mac you will have more than one frequently. And the first one is not guaranteed to be the right one.

Comment: Colin, you are right about the mac but regarding to the tag iOS I think it is about iOS devices GPUs. And as I know there are no iOS devices with multiple GPUs yet.